# How do I add a pop-up window in R Markdown that shows a message when I do file selection?

Tags: r, popup, r-markdown

Right now in my R Markdown I use:

source(file.choose())

to select which file to input. However, I would like to add a pop up window or somehow incorporate a message in the console that appears so that I can specify which file needs to be selected.

Right now I'm just using the message() function, but the message window only shows up in the console, and not as a pop up window. How can I get a pop-up window to appear, or alternatively incorporate the message to the pre-existing window that pops up when I do file selection?

Comment: Related: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-file-choose-file-choice-cancelled/9666 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/74001208/3358272. Bottom line, `knit`ting a document is run in a new R process and is generally not interactive in a way that does what you're intending. Perhaps you can convert your `.Rmd` file to a shiny app.

Comment: choose.files from the utils package has an option for a message. The msg appears at the top of the file explorer.